# Soluble group with arbitrary derived length

Tags: group-theory, solvable-groups

I found a reference to Malcev (1949): for each ordinal number $\aleph$ exist a hypoabelian group with derived length $\operatorname{der}(G)=\aleph$.

In particular: for each  $n\in\mathbb{N}$,  exists a soluble group G with derived length $\operatorname{der}(G)=n$.

I ask how one can construct an easy exemple (if possible the easiest).

Ps. I know that dihedral group $G=D_{2^{n+1}}$ is nilpotent with class of nilpotence $\operatorname{cl}(G)=n$ and that in general $\operatorname{der}(G)\le \operatorname{cl}(G)$. Perhaps in this case they are equal?

Comment: When you take commutators of upper triangular matrices, with each commutator the line of zeroes goes up by one. This will give you upper triangular matrix groups of increasing dimension as example.

Comment: @ahulpke These are indeed examples, but I think that their derived lengths increase logarithmically with increasing dimension rather than linearly (i.e. the line of zeroes roughly doubles each step rather than going up by one).

Comment: @DerekHolt You are (of course) right. Probably it is easiest to just note that these groups give arbitrary large derived length and then take derived subgroups to get to a particular $n$.